# PostgreSQL with Django: should I store static JSON in a separate MongoDB database?

Tags: django, database, mongodb, postgresql

**Context**

I'm making, a Django web application that depends on scraped API data.

The workflow:

A) I retrieve data from external API

B) Insert structured, processed data that I need in my PostgreSQL database (about 5% of the whole JSON)

I would like to add a third step, (before or after the "B" step) which will store the whole external API response in my databases. For three reasons:

1. I want to "freeze" data, as an "audit trail" in case of the API changes the content (It happened before)
2. API calls in my business are expensive, and often limited to 6 months of history.
3. I might decide to integrate more data from the API later.

Calling the external API again when data is needed is not possible because of 2) and 3)

Please note that the stored API responses will **never be updated** and **read performance is not really important**. Also, being able to query the stored API responses would be really nice, to perform exploratory analysis.

To provide additional context, there is a **few thousand API calls a day**, which represent around **50GB of data a year**.

**Here comes my question(s)**

Should I store the raw JSON in the same PostgreSQL database I'm using for the Django web application, or in a separate datastore (MongoDB or some other NoSQL database)?

If I go with storing the raw JSON in my PostgreSQL database, I fear that my web application **performance** will decrease due to the database being "bloated" (**50Mb of parsed SQL data in my Django database are equivalent to 2GB of raw JSON from the external API**, so integrating the full API responses in my database will multiply its size by 40)

What about **cost**? as all this is hosted on a DBaaS. I understand that the cost will increase greatly (due to the DBs size increase), but is any of the two options more cost effective?

Comment: Why not store the data in a document store? Just text files. That's usually the cheapest and with a smart classification they should be easy to retrieve (or just store the path to the file, using a Django FileField in a model).

Comment: Or just upload them to S3. Cheap as chips, permanent storage, easy to access by key.

Comment: Great idea, guys! This had not cross my mind before. It's simple and cheap, but I will lose the ability to easily query and perform aggregate on the JSON data, and perform exploratory analysis, which is important to us.

Comment: Thanks for theses inputs. Just updated my question to add the fact that the querying ability would be nice.